# A correlation test that measures when one quantity is small, the other one is too

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, correlation

I have two quantities $d_1,d_2$ (for example they can be dissimilarity measures) and I want to test the following hypothesis

When $d_1$ is small, so is $d_2$.

(So the relation between the two is not symmetric). Is there any correlation coefficient or significant test that can validate this hypothesis?

Comment: I assume $d_1, d_2$ are some real random variables. When you say "the relation between the two is not symmetric", what do you actually mean?

Comment: It means that you care whether $d_1$ being small implies the $d_2$ is, but you don't care about the reverse implication.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not quite sure what you need. But here is one way (possibly naive). Assume you observe a joint sample $\{ (d_1^{(i)}, d_2^{(i)}) \}_{i=1}^n$ of size $n$.

1. Decide a threshold $T$ below which $d_1$ is considered small.
2. Construct a new dataset $X = \{ (d_1^{(i)}, d_2^{(i)}) \mid d_1^{(i)} \le T, i=1,\ldots, n \}$ i.e., only keep the pairs containing small $d_1$
3. Run some standard test of correlation on the data $X$.

In short, I am saying that perhaps you can just use a standard test of correlation on the filtered data containing only small $d_1$. Of course, $T$ will depend on what you mean by "small".